# How to convert columns to rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a below table:
Table A with columns:

```
key col1,key col2,key col3,Non-key col1, Non-key col2,Non-key col3
01,01,01,A,B,C
```

I want to convert this table as shown below:

Table B:

```
key col1,key col2,key col3, Non-key name, Non-key val
01,01,01,Non-key col1,A
01,01,01,Non-key col2,B
01,01,01,Non-key col3,C
```

How can i convert above table A to table B?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT KEY_COL1, KEY_COL2, KEY_COL3, NON_KEY_COL1, NON_KEY_COL1 AS DATA
     FROM TABLE_A
   UNION ALL
   SELECT KEY_COL1, KEY_COL2, KEY_COL3, NON_KEY_COL1, NON_KEY_COL2 AS DATA
     FROM TABLE_A
   UNION ALL
   SELECT KEY_COL1, KEY_COL2, KEY_COL3, NON_KEY_COL1, NON_KEY_COL3 AS DATA
     FROM TABLE_A)
  ORDER BY KEY_COL1, KEY_COL2, KEY_COL3, NON_KEY_COL1, DATA;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/971ee/1)

Share and enjoy.